# Distributions on Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The dirichlet distribution is an example of a distribution on distributions. Are there other standard ones?

Comment: Why do you ask so raw questions ? The least thing you can do is to give a thorough reference where one can have information. I am sorry, I have lectured on probability but I haven't any **precise** idea about what is a "distribution on a distribution" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not nearly as common, but various attempts have been done to come up with distributions which are on the simplex but have less independence properties as the Dirichlet distribution.

See:

Logistic-Normal Distributions: Some Properties and Uses,
J. Aitchison and S. M. Shen,
Biometrika,
Vol. 67, No. 2 (Aug., 1980), pp. 261-272

and

A General Class of Distributions on the Simplex,
J. Aitchison,
Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series B (Methodological),
Vol. 47, No. 1 (1985), pp. 136-146

for some examples.